# redirect requests with slashes at the end of specific files to a non-slash URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a .htaccess rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^cart/?$ cart.php [L,NC]
```

It works fine if somebody accesses `www.domain.com/cart` but it messes up the structure of the website if somebody accesses `www.domain.com/cart/` (with the slash at the end).

Is there a way to, in addition to this rule, redirect people to the non-slash URL if they enter a slash at the end?

For example, if somebody accesses `www.domain.com/cart/` they are redirected to `www.domain.com/cart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule for trailing slash removal:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Make sure this rule is placed before internal rewrite rules like above.

Comment: Thanks :) Is there a way to make it for specific files only? Since I have some subdirectories that I wouldn't want affected.

Comment: Sub-directories won't be impacted due to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` condition but if you still want to target some specific patterns then it would be: `RewriteRule ^(cart|store)/$ $1 [R=302,L,NC]`

Comment: Actually, strangely when accessing the page with the slash, it now directs to http://www.domain.com/home/username/public_html/cart